# Angular API Objects

Tags: angularjs, api, object

Im creating a link grabbing the data from below

[image]

```
<a href="#">{{ product.category.value }}</a>
```

This works great but having problems grabbing a slug from the data object.

[image]

how do I get the slug?

```
<a ui-sref="{{ product.category.data.109923...slug }}">{{ product.category.value }}</a>
```

Please remember the 109923 object will change on different pages so cant be hard coded in. I hope someone can help

Answer (score 4):

Watch your changeable object by using `$watch` Like :

```
$scope.$watch('data', function (watch) {
  // watch your object here
})
```

May be this will help you

**OR**

You can use `ng-repeat` for your data, Like :

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data" >
  <a ui-sref="">{{ product.category.d.109923...slug }}</a>
</div>
```